# Make Windows 10 taskbar autohide when always on top

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I want Windows 10 taskbar to auto hide, but to always be available to come visible on top. At present when auto hide is enabled with always on top also enabled the taskbar does not appear

Comment: It does always come out on top.  Are you using the correct Autohide setting?  There is a setting for Desktop and a setting for Tablet.  Use the Desktop setting.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not actually in Tablet mode, which forces the taskbar to be always hidden and only one app is visible at a time.

Comment: I am not using tablet mode, indeed I always wonder why there is a tablet mode!

Answer (score 0):

Press the Windows key on the keyboard to bring up the Start Menu.

This should also make the taskbar appear.

Comment: Works fine in WIndows 8